# Why aren't Google Docs results appearing in Chrome's omnibox results?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I'm often searching for docs according to keywords in their title. Strangely, Chrome matches items from the browsing history that contain such keywords in their title but results from google docs don't appear.

Any ideas why this is happening or how to work around it?